# If Condition is not invoking inside

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

My if condition in the following code is not working ....

I thought my if condition would be wrong but then the code should have invoked the else condition but it is not doing soo.

```dart
class polyline {
    List<LatLng> _listltlg=[];


    start_record() {
        BackgroundLocation.startLocationService();

        BackgroundLocation.getLocationUpdates((location) {

            if(_listltlg.isEmpty){
                print('2nd if statement');
                _listltlg.add(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude));

            }

            else{
                print('Else case');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hello, the first time the callback is called, the list "_listltlg" IS empty.

Comment: Hello Sanjog, if it worked can you accept the answer below as the solution? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, the first time the callback is called, the list "_listltlg" IS empty.